# Spring MVC request and prototype scope not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, scope

In my Spring Application, below is the Scenario:

I have a Controller `A`. Another bean `B` defined with scope `Request`.

```
@Service("name")
@Scope("request")
class B{
   private String name;
   public void init(String name){
     this.name = name
}
}
```

And

```
@Controller
class A{

@Autowired
@Qualifier("name")
B ob;

//using B
}
```

1. Now when I run the application, I get the exception that a new bean could not be created.
2. If I change the scope to `prototype`. And If I print hashCode of B for every request, I get the same output, which means it is not injecting new object for every request.
3. Above if solved will still not be thread-safe as the `ob` reference will point to a new prototype object or request object and other requests which are processed will refer to new `B` object. Best would be to get the referance to the main Spring MVC applciation context and then getBean from that inside a method. This way locally I can access it and get a new Instance. But how do I solve the thread-safety issue.

Answer (score 1):

@Controller is in the scope Singleton. Use proxied beans.

```
@Service("name")
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
class B{
}
```